# How to add rel nofollow to this?

Tags: nofollow

How can i add rel="nofollow" to this?

```
echo " <a href='";
the_permalink();
echo "' >"."(...)"."</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure but try this

```
echo " <a href='";
the_permalink();
echo "' rel='nofollow'>"."(...)"."</a>";
```

also have a look on this
`<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">(...)</a>`

Comment: That's right. I know it's right.